# multiple sort fields on multiple tables without join sql

Tags: mysql

How to do multiple sort without Join on tables? I'm able to sort fine by audDt but I'm unable to do a secondary sort on siteSt. Here is my code:

```
$sorc451sql = "Select * FROM table1 ORDER BY audDt";
while ($sorc451row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc451res)) {
    $sorc451arycust[$i][6]  = $sorc451row['gropID'];


    $sorc452sql = "Select * FROM table2 WHERE gropID=".$sorc451arycust[$i][6];
    while ($sorc452row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc452res)) {
        $sorc452arycust[$i][12]  = $sorc452row['siteSt'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you avoiding joins? MySQL developers have spent years making them as fast as possible. Why isnt' a order by siteSt on the second query possible?

Comment: I'm editing inherited code and thought I could quickly fix this code without re-doing entire code.  Also, I tried adding SORT BY siteST in second select statement and it didn't sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its a quick fix:

```
$sorc451sql = "Select t1.gropID AS gropID, t2.siteSt AS siteSt FROM table1 t1 JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.gropID=t2.gropId ORDER BY audDt, SiteSt";
while ($sorc451row = mysqli_fetch_array($sorc451res)) {
    $sorc451arycust[$i][6]  = $sorc451row['gropID'];
    $sorc452arycust[$i][12] = $sorc452row['siteSt'];
}
```

It looks like table1 isn't used so the following looks sufficient as a query:

```
$sorc451sql = "Select gropID, siteSt FROM table2 ORDER BY audDt, SiteSt";
```

Comment: Thanks Dan.  table1 is being extensively used.  I just cleaned up the code here in stackoverflow to make it easier for everyone to follow.  I guess I'll have to bite the bullet and use Join

Comment: Its not used in the example you gave which is what I was referring to.